# Kernel nonparametric regression

Tags: regression, machine-learning, nonparametric

One of the methods for nonparametric regression is using kernels.
My question is what are the conditions on the kernels functions in this method?
In other words how can I decide if a given function can be used as a kernel?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notion of a *kernel* has a strict mathematical definition (from [here](http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~bartlett/courses/281b-sp08/7.pdf)):

> **Definition**. $k : \mathcal{X} \times \mathcal{X} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a
>   *kernel* if
>
> 1. $k$ is symmetric: $k(x,y) =k(y,x)$.
> 2. $k$ is positive semi-definite, i.e., $\forall x_1,x_2,...,x_n \in \mathcal{X}$, the ”Gram Matrix” $K$ defined by $K_{ij}=k(x_i,x_j)$ is
>      [positive semi-definite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive-definite_matrix). (A matrix $M \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ is
>      positive semi-definite if $\forall a \in \mathbb{R}^n, a'Ma\ge0$.)

Intuition behind a kernel is that it implicitly maps its input to some space (possibly infinite-dimensional), and then computes an inner product in that space:

$$
k(x, y) = \phi(x)^T \phi(y)
$$

Then $K$ is effectively a [Gram matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gramian_matrix), so you have to check if it's symmetric and positive-definite. This is not something you can test on a computer, you'll have to prove it mathematically.

[Mercer's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercer%27s_theorem) says that a kernel can be represented as 
$$
k(s, t) = \sum_{j=1}^\infty \lambda_j e_j(t) e_j(s)
$$
for some non-negative $\lambda$. From this form it easily follows that $K$ is positive semi-definite. So if you can represent your function in a form of RHS of the above equation, your function is a kernel.

You can also show a function is a kernel if you decompose it into a combination of known-to-be kernels:

- Sum of two kernels is a kernel
- A kernel multiplied by a **positive** number is a kernel